# How to categorize the features of website in organic search results?

Tags: seo

How can we categorize the features of any particular website like SO has.

Careers, Questions,Login likewise.

Thanks.

[image: Categorize site features]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to google but if you have a good site structure maybe it will increase your chances -
[source](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)

Edit:
Now there is a way to categorize the features of a particular website and more - here is a good explanation:
http://dashburst.com/google-search-what-are-rich-snippets/

Answer (score 1):

'Usually' to do this:

1) You need navigation links above the fold that are not changed often, i.e. they stick for a long time.

2) Your site needs to rank at position number 1, for your main brand name. Example: A search for stackoverflow, or bing, returns the respective sites on all google variations (local/country tld's). What this means is google 100% recognizes that "your brand name" keyword should be undoubtedly associate with your website.

3) Your site needs to be a authority site with great content or/and reputation in social circles. (This is the most vague point actually!)

You achieve the first 2 points easily, the 3rd one is tricky!